# Changing components via dispatching event to parent component

Tags: svelte

I have created a sandbox for this as it is more easily understood there. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-playground-forked-dz7x8?file=/Page1.svelte

I am currently trying to change which component is displayed on the main page via passing the component through an Event Dispatcher.

```
    import Page2 from "./Page2.svelte"

    let dispatch = createEventDispatcher;
    function clickHandler(){
        dispatch("changeView", Page2)
    }
</script>
<main>
  <button on:click={clickHandler}>To Page 2</button>
  <h1> Page 1 </h1>
</main>
```

When this is dispatched it is handled by the parent component App.svelte to then change the component in 
 `<svelte:component this={view} on:changeView={changeView} />`

```
  let view = Page1
  const changeView = (e) => {
    view = e.detail;
  }
</script>
<main>

  <svelte:component this={view} on:changeView={changeView} />

</main>
```

But the error I am receiving: 
Uncaught Error: Function called outside component initialization.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, any help on how to change between pages in a similar manner would be a great help.

Comment: Yep, you missed calling the fn `createEventDispatcher()`. Everything looks good!

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad 
Thank you, i have changed it and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Golamrabbi-azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13309282/golamrabbi-azad) I missed some bloody parenthesis after createEventDispatcher in Page1 and 2....

```
let dispatch = createEventDispatcher; //should be
let dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
```

Thank you!